# Change layout on orientation changes with tabs on android?

Tags: android, sdk

I have an app, with some tabs and a login dialog when the app i opened. My problem is now that I want to have the layout to change when the phone is rotated, but as I have noticed is that the activity is destroyed and then recreated which caused the login popup to occur again.

I have tried the "KeyBoardHidden|orientation" in the manifest, but then I am not able to get the layout to change when I rotate the phone.

Is there a way to force a refresh of the view on the android platform at runtime ?

Comment: You should be able to use KeyBoardHidden|orientation and have the layout autorotate. Do you overwrite onConfigurationChanged?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make the activity refresh it's layout. I'm currently able to make a toast message when the orientation changes, by overriding onConfigurationChanged and using KeyBoardHidden|orientation in the manifest.

Comment: Not really a solution for the problem as such, but perhaps an alternative way to deal with this is to simply store in the SharedPreferences whether the user is logged in or not. You can then simply decide on startup if you need to display the login dialog.

Comment: Yes, but who does I then have that variable cleared when the app is actually closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use KeyBoardHidden|orientation and have the layout autorotate itself.

You need to call super.onConfigurationChanged in the method in which you create the Toast.
The activity will then take the current layout and rotate it. This means that this won't give you the correct answer if you have two different layout files in layout-land and the default layout folder.

If you have two different layout files your activity should destroy itself and recreate the layout from scratch in onCreate. For this you should override [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). In onSaveInstanceState you will get a Bundle that you can use to store a boolean that determines if the dialog was presented to the user. This bundel will then be passed to your onCreate method after the activity was recreated. You then would check if the bundle that is supplied to onCreate is null if it is not you can extract the boolean and check if the dialog was presented.

Comment: Works great after fixing a few bugs and getting the syntax right :) Great ! Thanks..